# JSESSIONID suffixed with .undefined

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, jboss7.x

I have a Spring Web MVC application running in Jboss AS 7.1. When I check the session id of the application (by looking at the session cookie using Firebug from Firefox), it has `.undefined` suffixed with it. For example,

```
Ur1bLe3UDdWJ9xm0ZDbMfZvJ.undefined
```

I worked out a sample servlet session program and checked the session id and it is the same. I would like to know why we have `.undefined` as part of session id? I think this will not have any impact on the application, but wanted to know why the session id is created like this. If anyone knows about this, please clarify.

Comment: https://community.jboss.org/thread/201760

Answer (score 10):

If I am not mistaken in JBOSS 7.1 the `.undefined` part is due to the `instance-id` not being configured in the `standalone.xml` file.

The following addition to the `standalone.xml` file would replace the .undefined with a configured text:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" 
           default-virtual-server="default-host" 
           native="false" 
           instance-id="hostA">
```

There is also this discussion here: [community.jboss.org](https://community.jboss.org/thread/201760?tstart=0)